# What are the health benefits of vegetarianism?

Tags: health, vegetarian-diet

Are there any known health benefits of being a [vegetarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism)?

Does it prevent or lower the risk of any diseases?

> Vegetarianism is the practice of abstaining from the consumption of meat.

Comment: Are you asking about all meat-free diets, or a specific kind of vegetarianism like lacto-ovo? Are you in fact asking "What are the health benefits of not eating meat?"

Comment: Health benefits of vegetarianism in general, so basically benefits of not eating meat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gave an [answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/1317/120) on Health Stack Exchange. Maybe it's worth quoting it here:

> This subject is very broad and a detailed answer would require to be a
>   whole book. Shortly I can say that vegetarians and vegans have lower
>   rates of **mortality** (both by ischemic heart disease and total)
>   (1-3) and lower incidence rates of **diabetes** (4) and **cancer**
>   (5,6). Vegetarian diets are related to lower **blood pressure** (7,8),
>   lower **body weight** and **Body Mass Index** (BMI) (3,9), lower serum
>   levels of **total and LDL cholesterol** (3) (LDL is "the bad one"),
>   lower levels of C-reactive protein (10) (= show a lower lever of
>   chronical inflammation), and higher **insulin sensitivity** (11) (this
>   means they're less prone to diabetes). All this has been found
>   studying people that were already vegetarian or vegan at the moment of
>   the study.
>
> There are also experiments of people **switching** their diet to
>   vegetarian or vegan for medical purpose, say get rid of **diabetes or
>   heart disease**. A review of these successful experiments is
>   [here](https://lacucinadeibriganti.wordpress.com/articoli/diete-vegane-per-la-cura-delle-malattie-cardiovascolari-e-metaboliche/);
>   basically people who switched to a low-fat lof-glycemic index vegan
>   diet showed improvements in body weight, BMI, waist circumference,
>   total and LDL cholesterol, triglycerides, glycemic control, insulin
>   resistance, less need for drugs, reduction of cardiac events, reversal
>   of heart disease. (12-16)
>
> If you want to read more scientific studies on vegetarianism you might
>   also want to check these: 17-21.
>
> Finally I would like to add my personal experience (3 years vegetarian
>   + 8 vegan): I feel better, my mind is more active, I can keep working or studying after lunch, I stopped having terrible pain in the
>   intestine (probably due to putrefaction of meat during digestion) and
>   my blood analysis are perfect.
>
> ### References
>
> 1. Chang-Claude J, Frentzel-Beyme R. Dietary and Lifestyle Determinants of Mortality among German Vegetarians. Int J Epidemiol.
>      1993;22(2):228-236. doi:10.1093/ije/22.2.228.
> 2. Thorogood M, Mann J, Appleby P, McPherson K. Risk of death from cancer and ischaemic heart disease in meat and non-meat eaters. BMJ.
>      1994;308(6945):1667-1670. doi:10.1136/bmj.308.6945.1667.
> 3. Key TJ, Fraser GE, Thorogood M, et al. Mortality in vegetarians and nonvegetarians: detailed findings from a collaborative analysis of
>      5 prospective studies. Am J Clin Nutr. 1999;70(3):516S-524. Available
>      at: http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/70/3/516s.short. Accessed May
>      15, 2015.
> 4. Snowdon DA, Phillips RL. Does a vegetarian diet reduce the occurrence of diabetes? Am J Public Health. 1985;75(5):507-512.
>      doi:10.2105/AJPH.75.5.507.
> 5. Huang T, Yang B, Zheng J, Li G, Wahlqvist ML, Li D. Cardiovascular disease mortality and cancer incidence in vegetarians: a meta-analysis
>      and systematic review. Ann Nutr Metab. 2012;60(4):233-40.
>      doi:10.1159/000337301.
> 6. Lanou AJ, Svenson B. Reduced cancer risk in vegetarians: an analysis of recent reports. Cancer Manag Res. 2010;3:1-8.
>      doi:10.2147/CMR.S6910.
> 7. Fu C-H, Yang CCH, Lin C-L, Kuo TBJ. Effects of long-term vegetarian diets on cardiovascular autonomic functions in healthy
>      postmenopausal women. Am J Cardiol. 2006;97(3):380-3.
>      doi:10.1016/j.amjcard.2005.08.057.
> 8. Appleby PN, Davey GK, Key TJ. Hypertension and blood pressure among meat eaters, fish eaters, vegetarians and vegans in EPIC-Oxford.
>      Public Health Nutr. 2002;5(5):645-54. doi:10.1079/PHN2002332.
> 9. Spencer EA, Appleby PN, Davey GK, Key TJ. Diet and body mass index in 38000 EPIC-Oxford meat-eaters, fish-eaters, vegetarians and vegans.
>      Int J Obes Relat Metab Disord. 2003;27(6):728-34.
>      doi:10.1038/sj.ijo.0802300.
> 10. Krajcovicova-Kudlackova M, Blazicek P. C-reactive protein and nutrition. Bratisl Lek Listy. 2005;106(11):345-7. Available at:
>       http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16541618. Accessed May 15, 2015.
> 11. Kuo C-S, Lai N-S, Ho L-T, Lin C-L. Insulin sensitivity in Chinese ovo-lactovegetarians compared with omnivores. Eur J Clin Nutr.
>       2004;58(2):312-6. doi:10.1038/sj.ejcn.1601783.
> 12. Barnard, N. D., Cohen, J., Jenkins, D. J. A., Turner-McGrievy, G., Gloede, L., Green, A., & Ferdowsian, H. (2009). A low-fat vegan
>       diet and a conventional diabetes diet in the treatment of type 2
>       diabetes: a randomized, controlled, 74-wk clinical trial. The American
>       Journal of Clinical Nutrition, 89(5), 1588S–1596S.
>       doi:10.3945/ajcn.2009.26736H
> 13. Ornish, D., Brown, S. E., Billings, J. H., Scherwitz, L. W., Armstrong, W. T., Ports, T. A., … Brand, R. J. (1990). Can lifestyle
>       changes reverse coronary heart disease? The Lancet, 336(8708),
>       129–133. doi:10.1016/0140-6736(90)91656-U
> 14. Esselstyn, C. B. (1999). Updating a 12-year experience with arrest and reversal therapy for coronary heart disease (an overdue requiem
>       for palliative cardiology). The American Journal of Cardiology, 84(3),
>       339–341. doi:10.1016/S0002-9149(99)00290-8
> 15. Jenkins, D. J. A., Kendall, C. W. C., Marchie, A., Faulkner, D. A., Wong, J. M. W., de Souza, R., … Connelly, P. W. (2003). Effects of
>       a dietary portfolio of cholesterol-lowering foods vs lovastatin on
>       serum lipids and C-reactive protein. JAMA, 290(4), 502–10.
>       doi:10.1001/jama.290.4.502
> 16. Jenkins, D. J. A., Kendall, C. W. C., Faulkner, D., Vidgen, E., Trautwein, E. A., Parker, T. L., … Connelly, P. W. (2002). A dietary
>       portfolio approach to cholesterol reduction: combined effects of plant
>       sterols, vegetable proteins, and viscous fibers in
>       hypercholesterolemia. Metabolism: Clinical and Experimental, 51(12),
>       1596–604. doi:10.1053/meta.2002.35578
> 17. Craig, Winston, J., Mangels, Ann, R., Craig, W. J., & Mangels, A. R. (2009). Position of the American Dietetic Association: vegetarian
>       diets. Journal of the American Dietetic Association, 109(7), 1266–82.
>       doi:10.1016/j.jada.2009.05.027
> 18. Ferdowsian, H. R., & Barnard, N. D. (2009). Effects of plant-based diets on plasma lipids. The American Journal of Cardiology, 104(7),
>       947–56. doi:10.1016/j.amjcard.2009.05.032
> 19. Jenkins, D. J. A., Kendall, C. W., Marchie, A., Jenkins, A. L., Augustin, L. S., Ludwig, D. S., … Anderson, J. W. (2003). Type 2
>       diabetes and the vegetarian diet. Am J Clin Nutr, 78(3), 610S–616.
>       Retrieved from http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/78/3/610S.short
> 20. Trapp, C. B., & Barnard, N. D. (2010). Usefulness of vegetarian and vegan diets for treating type 2 diabetes. Current Diabetes
>       Reports, 10(2), 152–8. doi:10.1007/s11892-010-0093-7
> 21. Trapp, C., & Levin, S. (2012). Preparing to Prescribe Plant-Based Diets for Diabetes Prevention and Treatment. Diabetes Spectrum, 25(1),
>       38–44. doi:10.2337/diaspect.25.1.38

Comment: I didn't go through all references, but (1) don't prove that vegetarianism is associated with lower mortality, though the authors appear to claim it. [The article](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article-pdf/22/2/228/2258304/22-2-228.pdf) shows that the statistic models used to get the results were built on the vegetarian cohort only. They compare "strict" vs. "moderate" vegetarians, not vegetarians vs. non-vegetarians. Also, the only vegetarianism-linked statistically significant association (p<.05) was that moderate vege females had a lower total mortality than strict vege females (table 3).

Comment: I'm ***not*** advocating that vegetarianism is unhealthy, I just point out that :
1. The first article is arguably intellectualy dishonest and of low scientific value as for evaluating the effects of vegetarianism on mortality;
2. It is better to read the method and result section of articles than the abstract because this is unfortunatly not uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

If the diet is *properly planned*, it can lead to several health benefits, which are indicated in this wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism):

- **Longevity** - in conjunction to other favorable life-style factors, it can lead to higher life expectancy:

> The researchers found that a combination of different lifestyle
>   choices could influence life expectancy by as much as 10 years.

- **Reducing of some specific health risks** like high blood pressure, cardiovascular disease, and cholesterol levels.

A general article that officially confirms possible benefits (for health and others) can be found [here](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/705344#vp_1).